# How to figure out which syntax rule is determining a character's color?

Tags: colorscheme

I want to design my own vim color scheme, so I'm starting with an existing color scheme that I think is pretty good, and fixing the parts I don't like.

The color scheme definition contains many syntax tags, a lot of which aren't totally clear. The task would be much easier if I could ask Vim:

> Which syntax rule is determining the color of the character under my cursor?

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty. One is my own [plugin](https://github.com/benknoble/vim-synstax), the code of which is straightforward:

```
" Show the highlight groups under the cursor
" Maintainer:       David Ben Knoble <ben.knoble@gmail.com>
" Last Change:      2018 May 11

if !has("syntax") || &compatible
  echohl ErrorMsg
  echomsg "vim-synstax requires the +syntax features"
  echohl None
  finish
endif

function! synstax#UnderCursor() abort
  let l:stack = synstax#Stack(line('.'), col('.'))
  if empty(l:stack)
    return "No syntax highlight groups under cursor"
  endif
  let l:names = synstax#Attributes(l:stack, 'name')
  return l:names
endfunction

function! synstax#Stack(line, col) abort
  return synstack(a:line, a:col)
endfunction

function! synstax#Attributes(stack, attr) abort
  let l:attr_func = printf('synIDattr(v:val, "%s")', a:attr)
  return map(a:stack, l:attr_func)
endfunction
```